# How to change WooCommerce notice "info" background color on smaller screens?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, media-queries, mobile-devices

Okay so firstly I'm no expert coder (hence the question) but I've managed to change the WooCommerce info bar color for desktop viewing, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the color for mobile devices.

This is what works for desktop viewing:

```css
.woocommerce-info {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

And I tried multiple similar combinations of the below code with no success:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .woocommerce-info
  background-color: #000; !important
}
```

Comment: There is a typo missing `{` after class in media query.

Comment: Thanks for your input...I tried adding the { after the .woocommerce-info class in media query, but unfortunately it's not made any difference :-(

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your attempt… Try the following for small screen devices *(I have used a random color that you will replace with the right desired one)*:

```css
/* For larger screens (first) */
.woocommerce-info {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}

/* For smaller screens (after) */
@media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
    .woocommerce-info {
        background-color: #AA00B6 !important;
    }
}
```

Code goes in *style.css* file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works. You may try without `!important`, to see if it works...

On small screen devices, you will get something like:

[image]

On larger screen devices, you will get the default behavior like:

[image]

---

In some cases, you may insert those CSS rules after all existing ones using:

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'wp_head_custom_css', 99999);
function wp_head_custom_css() {
    ?>
    <style>
    /* For larger screens (first) */
    .woocommerce-info {
        background-color: #000000 !important;
    }

    /* For smaller screens (after) */
    @media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
        .woocommerce-info {
            background-color: #AA00B6 !important;
        }
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hey @LoicTheAztec, thanks for your input, it's much appreciated but I'm still struggling getting it to work. I copied & pasted your code into my child theme but it hasn't made any difference? I'm really confused now lol! 

Please see gif image:

https://i.postimg.cc/gkDx0t3m/mobile-view.gif

Comment: I have added something at the end of my answer, first remove everything related you added, then add that code snippet, to see if there is a change.

Comment: Wow! that seems to have done the trick on the info bar, but upon testing, when I empty the basket, for some reason I'm getting a big black rectangle box behind the cart image and the top info bar is in green? Ideally the emptied basket page should have no black background. I've created another gif to demonstrate: https://i.postimg.cc/tg5vkyhc/mobile-view-1.gif